# Generic JSON decoder

Tags: swift, generics

I found the following on the web, and it is what I want as a generic decoder

```
func decode<T: Decodable>(_ data: Data, completion: @escaping ((T) -> Void)) {
    do {
        let model = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
        completion(model)
    } catch (let error) {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

However I can't call it: I get `Type '()' cannot conform to 'Decodable'` when using the following:

```
let dec = decode(data, completion: {
    
})
```

Comment: data is Data (the Type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to store the `decode` function (and) using a completion with `@escaping`. You can return directly decoded response handling the error case with optional.

Modify your function like:

```
func decode<T: Decodable>(_ data: Data) -> T? {
    do {
        return try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
    } catch (let error) {
        print(error)
        return nil
    }
}
```

**or** *(just return optional response)*:

```
func decode<T: Decodable>(_ data: Data) -> T? {
    return try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
}
```

**Let your response is:**

```
struct Response: Decodable { }
```

**Usage:**

```
// Tell the compiler what the response is
let decodedResponse: Response? = decode(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to provide the completion parameter with the `Decodable` type specified. The method needs to be able to infer what type the completion parameter is expected in the completion block.

```
struct Response: Decodable { }
let dec = decode(data, completion: { (response: Response) in

})
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling your `decode` function incorrectly. Firstly, you need to tell the compiler what `T` is. You can do this by type annotating the closure input argument. Secondly, you should not assign the return value of your function, since the return value is `Void`, there's nothing you can do with a `Void`.

```
// Replace `Int` with your `Decodable` conformant type
decode(data, completion: { (response: Int) -> Void in
    // use `response` here
})
```